# Can I transform a web.config with an Albacore task?

Tags: .net, albacore

When I publish from Visual Studio 2010, it transforms the `web.config` according to the  `Web.Debug.config` or `Web.Release.config`. Is there a way to do that with `aspnet_compiler` or something else in Albacore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [similar question](http://groups.google.com/group/albacoredev/browse_thread/thread/e4129fa1f4bec994) was asked recently on the mailing list. I don't know if this is the same situation that you are facing, but hopefully it will help you out. Based on the needs of that person, I recommended the following for the msbuild task.

```
CLIENT_SOURCE_DIR = 'C:/Builds/MySolution/Source/Client/'
PUBLISH_CLIENT_DIR = 'C:/Builds/MySolution/Publish/Client/'

desc 'Publish the web site'
msbuild :publish do |msb|
  msb.solution = "#{CLIENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Client.csproj"
  msb.targets [:Clean, :Rebuild]
  msb.properties = { 
    :configuration => :Release, 
    :UseWPP_CopyWebApplication => true, 
    :PipelineDependsOnBuild => false,
    :webprojectoutputdir => "#{PUBLISH_CLIENT_DIR}/",
    :outdir => "#{PUBLISH_CLIENT_DIR}/bin/"
  }
end
```